# Script is creating duplicates: create google calendar event On Form Submit

Tags: google-apps-script

This script worked good almost a year. Both triggers are "On Form Submit".
Approximately one week ago these two functions started making duplicates: two same emails, two same calendar events. I went through bunch of posts here & I cannot get how to get rid of this issue. I'm not a programmer, the code below I took from different sources. Recently added there LockService but with no success.
Can anyone explain what is wrong with the code?
Thank you.

```
function BOOKemail(email, subject, message, options) 
{ 
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
var success = lock.tryLock(5000);
if (!success) {
Logger.log('tryLock failed to get the lock');
return
}
var email = "abc@abc.org"
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var lr = rows.getLastRow();
var subject = "Request: "+sheet.getRange(lr,2).getValue()+"     "+sheet.getRange(lr,1).getValue(); 
var message = "Issue: "+sheet.getRange(lr,3).getValue()+"     "+"Employee name:     "+sheet.getRange(lr,4).getValue();
var options = {name:"ABC"};

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
lock.releaseLock();

}


function createEvent(title, date, desc)
{
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
var success = lock.tryLock(5000);
if (!success) {
Logger.log('tryLock failed to get the lock');
return
}
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var lr = rows.getLastRow();
var title = sheet.getRange(lr,1).getValue()+"       "+"Request: "+sheet.getRange(lr,2).getValue()+"   "+"Issue: "+sheet.getRange(lr,3).getValue()+"   [F]";
var desc = "Issue: "+sheet.getRange(lr,3).getValue()+"     "+"Employee name:    "+sheet.getRange(lr,4).getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('ABC') [0];
var date = new Date();
var event = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {description : desc});
lock.releaseLock();
};
```

Comment: You might want to consider searching the Issue Tracker and maybe reporting it:  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Why cant those functions be combined?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an underlying Google issue, your code is fine.

See the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4752

I Was experiencing the same problem with a script I had developed for a client, but in about the last 30 minutes the duplicate issue seems to have stopped happening. So I'm hoping Google has now fixed the underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I tried everything: the issue shows up from time to time. I think nothing can be done till internal issue 4752 is solved.